# How do I apply this WordPress filter?

Tags: wordpress

I need help to apply this WordPress filter...

```
apply_filters( ‘wcmp_widget_vendor_product_sales_report_days_range’, 7, $requestData, $vendor );
```

This filter is what has been provided to me by the plugin makers (WC Marketplace) - all they said was "in order to display product sold over 60 days, you have to do custom code. For this use this filter `apply_filters( ‘wcmp_widget_vendor_product_sales_report_days_range’, 7, $requestData, $vendor );` and change the value change 7 to 60."

I am new to WordPress coding and am not sure how to go about applying this filter. The only reference to this filter in their plugins code is in this file https://github.com/dualcube/dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor/blob/master/classes/class-wcmp-ajax.php on line 2905.

Any help would be great. I have already looked in the WordPress references but I am clueless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code in your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
// To change the default value of `$days_range` from 7 days to 60 days
function lh_wcmp_vendor_custom_sales_report( $days_range ) {
    $days_range = 60; // you can adjust days here as you needed
    return $days_range;
}
add_filter( 'wcmp_widget_vendor_product_sales_report_days_range', 'lh_wcmp_vendor_custom_sales_report', 10 );
```

Though I don't have data to test it, but I am sure it will work for you.

Comment: I now have another question... the sales report widget is on the dashboard, I have created a new page called 'Sales' and pasted in the same code from the dashboard widget (https://github.com/dualcube/dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor/blob/master/templates/vendor-dashboard/dashboard-widgets/wcmp_vendor_product_sales_report.php) my idea is to show all sold products over the past year on this page. So the dashboard version shows 60 days but this page shows 365. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: @AshleyYoung It would be better to post a new question. Also include the code for the new **Sales** page.

Comment: I have now created a new post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54555891/wc-marketplace-sales-report can you take a look to see if you can help?